# Azure DevOps Pipeline Build - register COM DLL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

Background:
Few Projects in my solution, are dependent on COM libraries. So these COM DLLs has to be registered before building the actual solution.

In Azure DevOps - Pipeline - Build - Task,
I added a "Command Line" agent job, with the following command,

Scenario 1:
C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe /s [DLLFilePath]\[DLLName].dll

Scenario 2:
CD [DLLFilePath] 
C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe /s [DLLName].dll

But both the scenarios return the same error during build time,
**[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '3'.**

Note: 
The DLL is copied to the above mentioned location using a seperate agent job, before invoking regsvr32.

[DLLFilePath]\[DLLName].dll is a local path in the build agent, say c:\..\someLibrary.dll

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It's something that I want to attempt looking into. I've got a decent number of PCs I want to deploy a DLL to without having to manually re-register every time I make a change.

Comment: Don't know if this will be helpful but Ray Chen has a full post on error 3 resulting from RegSvr32.exe.  Granted it's not related to Azure Pipelines but probably is relevant:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180921-00/?p=99795

Comment: Also I know that that regsvr32 does not work unless I do it as administrator.  Not sure how to do that in an Azure DevOps pipeline

Comment: Is your dll 32 or 64 bit? Counterintuitively ...\system32\regsvr32.exe is for registering 64 bit dlls. I have been able to successfully register 32 bit dlls on Azure pipelines using precisely your first script, but with an application path of C:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my project a have same problem (I think). 
**Error after build: COM library no registered.**

But I registered my COM library with C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe and registered x64 dll.

My solution: I change BuildPlatform from "Any CPU" to "x64". 
[image]